# What is the difference between dagger.android.support.DaggerApplication and dagger.android.DaggerApplication?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

When I was experimenting with Dagger2.22 I found similar classes 
**dagger.android.support.DaggerApplication** and **dagger.android.DaggerApplication**

```
public class BaseApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
    }
}
```

accidentally i had used dagger.android.DaggerApplication instead of dagger.android.support.DaggerApplication and was getting **android.app.Application cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method** , what is the difference between these two classes? is it something related to compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is related to compatibility. The `dagger.android.support` is compatible with more versions just like the Android support libraries. So it will work on lower Android versions, too.
You can check the [source code](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/java/dagger/android) for more info